# Error running enable-migration command in package manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations

I'm running the command:

> "Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName GiftContex -StartUpProjectName
>   GiftExchange -ConnectionStringName GiftExchangeEntities"

I received an error message after running it saying:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The Entity Framework provider type
>   'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices,
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file
>   for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'
>   could not be loaded. Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is
>   used and that the assembly is available to the running application.

I have entity framework 6.1.1 installed in my datalayer, the layer I'm "enabling migrations" from and it seems like I'm pointing to the correct connection string, but I'm not sure why its failing to enable migrations and create the initfile and configuration file in my datalayer project?

I have this code in the web.config file in the mvc project:

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory,
 EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"     type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

Comment: Update: it is actually creating the migrations folder and the configuration file inside, but not the initialized file.

Comment: Update2: I can't perform an update-database throwing the same error message.

Comment: looks like EntityFramework.SqlServer is missing, try uninstalling and re-installing the EF nuget package.